# jQuery Steps plugin async demo

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, wizard, demo, jquery-steps

I am coding using the jQuery Steps plugin and have a question about the async demo.

Here is the page code:

```
<section id="async">
    <h2 class="page-header">Async Content Loading Example</h2>
    <div id="wizard-7">
        <h3>Async Step</h3>
        <section data-mode="async" data-url="/Examples/AsyncContent">
        </section>

        <h3>Second Step</h3>
        <section>
            <p>Donec mi sapien, hendrerit nec egestas a, rutrum vitae dolor. Nullam venenatis diam ac ligula elementum pellentesque. 
                In lobortis sollicitudin felis non eleifend. Morbi tristique tellus est, sed tempor elit. Morbi varius, nulla quis condimentum 
                dictum, nisi elit condimentum magna, nec venenatis urna quam in nisi. Integer hendrerit sapien a diam adipiscing consectetur. 
                In euismod augue ullamcorper leo dignissim quis elementum arcu porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Vestibulum leo velit, blandit ac tempor nec, ultrices id diam. Donec metus lacus, rhoncus sagittis iaculis nec, malesuada a diam. 
                Donec non pulvinar urna. Aliquam id velit lacus.</p>
        </section>

        <h3>Third Step</h3>
        <section>
            <p>Morbi ornare tellus at elit ultrices id dignissim lorem elementum. Sed eget nisl at justo condimentum dapibus. Fusce eros justo, 
                pellentesque non euismod ac, rutrum sed quam. Ut non mi tortor. Vestibulum eleifend varius ullamcorper. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                Donec diam massa, porta vel dictum sit amet, iaculis ac massa. Sed elementum dui commodo lectus sollicitudin in auctor mauris 
                venenatis.</p>
        </section>

        <h3>Forth Step</h3>
        <section>
            <p>Quisque at sem turpis, id sagittis diam. Suspendisse malesuada eros posuere mauris vehicula vulputate. Aliquam sed sem tortor. 
                Quisque sed felis ut mauris feugiat iaculis nec ac lectus. Sed consequat vestibulum purus, imperdiet varius est pellentesque vitae. 
                Suspendisse consequat cursus eros, vitae tempus enim euismod non. Nullam ut commodo tortor.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

Can someone please explain how the data is loaded from the Examples/AsyncContent and is displayed on the page? Is there some documentation on how to use this feature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get any answer??..Its poorly documented.

Answer (score 0):

by putting the attribute data-mode="async" and data-url="urltocontent" into the step's content the script will deal with it all.

i didn't need to do any further configuration to make it work.